# How to use RxSwift Observable<Int>.interval?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to emit a sequence on a ”pulse” at a given time interval. Totally new to everything Rx, but thought this would do it:

```
import RxSwift
let db = DisposeBag()

_ = Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .debug("interval")
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print($0)
    })
    .addDisposableTo(db)
```

But it only outputs:

```
2017-09-25 06:12:41.161: interval -> subscribed
```

And nothing more. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: What's a lifetime of your dispose bag - `db`? Try again without this line: `.addDisposableTo(db)`

Comment: Tried it now. With or without `.addDisposable` it stil doesn't seem to emit anything. I've added the complete code in my playground now. The dispose bag should be alive.

Comment: This is really weird, because of this code works for me

Comment: What version of RxSwift do you use?

Comment: I think it is latest, I have this in my Podfile: `pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 3.0'`

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the code should work! I was starting to pull off all my hair here.

Comment: It's not a latest version. Change to 4.0

Comment: I'm using Swift 3, so RxSwift 3 too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The dispose bag is alive as it should be. However, the playground execution ends as soon as the last instruction is run, hence the problem.

In order to tell the playground to continue running after everything was executed, you have to import `PlaygroundSupport` and tell the page to continue running:

```
import RxSwift
import PlaygroundSupport

let db = DisposeBag()

Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .debug("interval")
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print($0)
    })
    .addDisposableTo(db)

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: in RxSwift5:
```Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(1.0), scheduler:  ...```

Comment: How could stop this timer?

Comment: You create an instance of `var timerDisposable: Disposable?` and return the output if `Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(1.0), scheduler: ...` to `timerDisposable`. Finally you can stop the timer by calling `timerDisposable?.dispose()`.